# What is the て form of しない?

Tags: grammar

The hypothetical scenario is given as follows.

- Yesterday night I played game and intentionally did not do the homework. I did not forget for sure. :-)
- This morning the teacher asked me and I want to pretend to regret what I did.

From this scenario, I want to say something that makes use of ～てしまいました grammar.

> 宿題を[the て form of しない]しまいました。

What is the て form of しない ?

Comment: It's しないでしまいました, but this usage is not common.

Comment: [これ](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22881/9831) と [これ](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15474/9831)  は参考になりますか。

Comment: I think you cannot use しまいました with ない形. You should instead use something like 宿題をしないで寝てしまいました。

Comment: This [question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28846/11104) might give you a hint on how to excuse yourself, but anyway it would be hard to end with してしまいました, this would rather be a part of the reason like 宿題をしようとしましたが、〜してしまって、できませんでした。

Answer (score 2):

しないで would be the て form of しない, but in conversation you don't hear the negative form of a verb used with しまいました. Instead you use the positive form of a verb + て form + しまいました. So for example, 宿題をしてしまいました would emphasize that you did your homework. If you didn't do the homework you need to connect it's negative with another verb. For example, 宿題をしないで来てしまいました。