# Does ようとした always mean failure to try doing something?

Tags: grammar

Consider the following sentences.

> A: 昨日たこ焼きを作ってみた。
>
> B: 昨日たこ焼きを作ろうとした。

A means that "I tried to make takoyaki and I really made it."

## Questions

Does B always mean that "I tried to make takoyaki but I (did not)/(failed to) make it." ?

Comment: A doesn't mean "I tried to make" but "I tried making".

Comment: @user4092, what's the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, B just says "I tried to make it", and it says nothing about the result, whether or not "I" was able to actually make it.

But as you might guess, a sentence like B is usually followed by something that prevents the speaker from doing so smoothly. Ultimately, the speaker may or may not succeed.

> 昨日たこ焼きを作ろうとした。だけど近所の店でタコが売られていなかったので、諦めた。
>
> 昨日たこ焼きを作ろうとした。おいしいたこ焼きができた。: Huh?
>
> 昨日たこ焼きを作ろうとした。だけど近所の店でタコが売られていなかった。車で1時間走ってタコを買ってきて、最終的にはおいしいたこ焼きができた。: OK

Comment: Doesn't B include a situation when you just intended to do something (thought about doing something), but "failed" (or resigned because of some condition) even before trying?

Comment: If you just thought of doing something, "～しようと思った" is mainly used. "～しようとした" is different, and usually means you actually attempted to do it at least for a moment (eg ネットで作り方を調べる、立ち上がって冷蔵庫の中身を見る、…)

Comment: Does 宿題をしようとしたとき、友達が来た indicate that I actually did something? Or just intended to do my homework?

Comment: Somewhere between you decide to do your homework ***now***, and walk to your desk, open a textbook and actually start your homework. A lazy boy may say to his mother "今、宿題をしようとしてた!" for hours, though.